# c++ Find average of negatives with function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, average

This code to find average of the negative elements works fine when I put everything in `main`. The problem is when I try to split it to functions. How can I connect the elements from `cinarray` and `negative_average` function?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cinarray();
    negative_average();
}

int cinarray()
{
    int A[3][3];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << "\n A[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "]=";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t";

        cout << "\n";
    }

    // compute average of only negative values
    int negative_average()
    {
        int negCount = 0;
        int average = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                if (A[x][y] < 0) {
                    ++negCount;
                    average += A[x][y];
                }

            }
        }
        if (negCount > 0) {
            average /= negCount;
            cout << "Average of only negative values \n" << average;
        }
    }
}
```

and one more thing why the error list show that i need ";"

```
int negative_average()
{ //here
    int negCount = 0;
    int average = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot define a function inside another function's body, that's why the "`;` needed here" error. Move it to the global scope. In this case, you can create `int A[3][3];` in `main`, and declare your functions accordingly:

```
void cinarray(int A[3][3]);                // why int return type?
void negative_average(const int A[3][3]);
```

Then pass `A` to both.

Comment: array needn't be passed  by reference explicitly, it is always passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

As an option define array in main of the and pass reference to `cinarray()` and `negative_average()`.

Do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int A[3][3];
    cinarray(A);
    negative_average(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Where:

```
int cinarray(int (&A)[3][3])
int negative_average(const int (&A)[3][3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array A isn't visible to both functions. You need to declare it in your main(), then pass it as an argument to your other functions.